# Django TinyMCE external_image_list_url breaks all admin urls

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, django-views

I have a pages app into which I have implemented TinyMCE for the main content.  This is working just fine.  I'm now trying to add the image list support as per [the Django/TinyMCE Docs](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#external-link-and-image-lists) but have stumbled upon a problem.  When I uncomment the external_image_list_url line below all my admin urls break?

```
content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={
    'cols': 80, 
    'rows': 30,
    #'external_image_list_url': reverse('mediamanager.views.imagelist')
}))
```

The mediamanager.views.imagelist is set up

```
url(r'^$', views.imagelist, name='imagelist'),
```

and works - http://csmatrix.local/gallery/ returns:

```
var tinyMCEImageList = [["(uploads/2015/10/20141205_142735.jpg", "/gallery/i/4"], ["(uploads/2015/10/treeladder.jpg", "/gallery/i/5"], ["(uploads/2015/10/treeladder_RwtzMjv.jpg", "/gallery/i/7"]]
```

the view itself looks like:

```
def imagelist(request):
  from tinymce.views import render_to_image_list
  objects = Image.objects.all()
  link_list = [(unicode(obj), obj.get_absolute_url()) for obj in objects]
  return render_to_image_list(link_list)
```

What could be wrong?  All admin urls are broken not just the page edit one.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

I managed to solve this problem with a bit of help from James @ [Django Users Group](http://django-users@googlegroups.com).   From looking at the reverse issue I ended up removing the function call entirely and just pasting in the URL. It works - not a perfect fix but a fix.

I'd paste the use group thread here but I'm currently blocked behind a work firewall so cannot access Google Groups.